# How to select nothing in tkinter combobox

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

My problem is something very basic and I tried searching everywhere, but couldn't find an answer so here I am with my first stackoverflow question!

I have a tkinter combobox in my program. When I first run the program, nothing is selected. I select a value from dropdown and everything works fine. My question is, how do I then again select 'nothing' in the combobox using the program? Meaning the combobox selection should be blank.

I tried using `.current(-1)` but that doesn't work.

Can someone set me in the right direction?

Comment: You can either add an empty string as the first item in the option list (so that you can select it in the dropdown list) or you can use `.set('')` to clear the selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `delete` method on the combobox to delete the current value.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def clear_combo():
    cb.delete(0, "end")

root = tk.Tk()
cb = ttk.Combobox(root, values=("one", "two", "three"))
b = ttk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_combo)

cb.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)
b.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```